# Add and use a "dispenser for sequence numbers" in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sequence

Wanting to use SQLite to help creating unique serial numbers for objects, I wonder whether I can use a database mechanism to get sequential numbers.

I see that an `autoincrement` primary key creates an entry in `sqlite_sequence` where `name` is the table's name and `seq` is number used last.

So I basically have three questions:

1. Is there a mechanism to add a dispenser to get autoincrementing numbers without disturbing the rest of the database?
2. If not, can I add my own entry to `sqlite_sequence`, or will it confuse the database?
3. If I can add an entry to `sqlite_sequence`, and it does not disturb the database, how to I safely get the next value (preferably using Perl's DBI)?

I tried a `select seq from sqlite_sequence where name=SOME_TABLE';` but that seems to return always the same number, so the table does not seem to have any magic built in.

Oracle seems to have a `CREATE SEQUENCE` construct.